# Homography Matrix

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to calculate a homography matrix so I can match two images together. I have a matrix named match_xy with each row equals x1,y1,x2,y2. (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) are matched coordinates in img1 and img2, respectively. How can I take the information from that matrix and construct a homography matrix? I can get this working by using the findHomography method built into opencv but I want to make my own homography method instead.

Comment: there is plenty of literature for it. One way is direct linear transform to get a linear system that can be sved or optimized. If you expect to have outliers in your matches, RANSAC is a very common approach. You can read a lot of the background in Zisserman's famous book or different slides from universities.

Comment: Is it Hartley's or Zisserman's book? :)  Hartley, R. Zisserman, A "Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision"  ISBN: 0521540518